# ways to monitor an object in R

Tags: r

I am hunting for ways to monitor when an object is updated, and do something (e.g. redraw a plot, print a message).

The ideal would be a generic function like:

```
watch(obj, fn)
```

where `fn` is called whenever `obj` is changed.

Or, are there any equivalents to `View` or `plot` which could do this?

Comment: I think you can use `?makeActiveBinding` for this.

Comment: Thanks Ben! How can I give you credit?

Comment: that's OK, I have lots of rep.  cheers. (You can mention me in your answer if you like)

Comment: by the way, I think you're also allowed/encourage to accept your own answer (so we can easily see that the question has been answered satisfactorily)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`makeActiveBinding` is just what I was looking for, suggested by Ben Bolker. A quick example:

```
makeActiveBinding("visibull", function(x) {
    if (! missing(x)) {
        .invisibull <<- x; 
        View(.invisibull)
    } else .invisibull
}, .GlobalEnv)

visibull <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10)
visibull
visibull$a <- visibull$a + 1
.invisibull
```

Comment: Very nice.  I'll copy that code and one of these days add it to my "cgwtools" package, with you as the author.